# Ubuntu SDK: How do I implement a "onClick" for an image in QML?

Tags: application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

I have a background image for my page, and I want to implement a sort of page refresh when the background is clicked. However, I didn't find any actions for the image element in QT quick.

What's the right way to implement this?

Comment: Did you try putting the image inside a QML `Component`? the `Component` should have that onClick event you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should do what you need by putting the Image into a [MouseArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html) component:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

MouseArea {
    width: my_background.width
    height: my_background.height
    Image {
        id: my_background
        source: "background.png"
    }
    onClicked: my_background.source = "background.png"
}
```